# How does the bootstrap-vue scoped-slot syntax for b-tables work behind the scenes?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, slots

When looking at the documentation I see you can insert dynamic content into the table using scoped slots and having access to the parent data. The pattern to archieve this is: v-slot:cell(Delete)="data".

I understand that the data are the slot-props and I also know that cell is the name of the slot and that Delete in this case is the delete column, but how does this work if one were to implement this in a component. Is the cell a function that is receiving the argument Delete as a string?

I've tried to find the correct documentation and answers but none seem specific to this pattern